# How to properly use sleep with print and random in python

Tags: python, random, counter, sleep, nonetype

I’m a novice and I have been trying to build a random countdown timer which picks a number between 0 and 10, and counts to zero from the selected integer. All while printing the countdown simultaneously. However, I keep getting errors from sleep().

```
import random
import time

x = random.randint(0,10)

y = time.sleep(x)

while y != 0:
    print(y)
```

Comment: This code doesn't give any errors. It doesn't do anything useful, but it runs fine.

Comment: What do you expect `y = time.sleep(x)` to do? You also never decremented `y`.

Comment: I thought "None" was an error. i expected an integer output.  Because wanted it to print it's output as a countdown. I tried a bunch of things with the print command but errors ensued. This was the simplest i could make it. I also wasn't aware i had to do anything else to y.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be help you:

```
import random
import time

countdown = random.randint(0,10)

for i in reversed(range(countdown)):
    print(str(i) + ' sec left')
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: This one is concise! Thanks. I'm sorry i didn't clarify this earlier. What i am concerned about is if sleep() will still delay the next function as part of a bigger block of code. I just need this snippet to track what the code is doing in terminal as opposed to looking at the gui. but essentially both time.sleep and the countdown should be the same integer before the next instruction.

Answer (score 0):

This code does what you want. Simply, inside while loop we `sleep` 1 second and decrement `x`, until we reach `x=0`.

```
import random
import time

x = random.randint(0, 10)
print("Starting countdown!")
while x>0:
   print(x)
   time.sleep(1)
   x-=1
print("Countdown ended!")
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time. It does but as part of a bigger block of code where timesleep takes the same integer from randint. and sleeps before executing i'm not particularly sure how time.sleep should be 1. i just want one random integer that does two things it time sleeps for the bigger code and it prints the countdown so i can track what timesleep is doing.

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you need. The `sleep` interval is the delay between numbers so it should be constant:

```
from random import randint
from time import sleep

x = randint(0,10)

def countdown(start_time):
    print("Counting from " + str(start_time))
    for n in range((start_time + 1)):
        y = start_time - n
        print(y)
        sleep(1) # Assumes 1 second delay between numbers

if __name__ == "__main__":
    countdown(x)
```

Comment: Thank you! however, i should have clarified this earlier. This code works well on its own but it's supposed to be part of a bigger block of code. where timesleep gets its argument from randint(). the purpose of this is so i can track what the code is doing in the terminal as opposed to watching the gui.

Comment: No problem. The answer by Yakir is probably closer to what you need then.